# Finding information about constructors in the UIKit documentation for Swift

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift

I'm currently trying to learn Swift by reading the book provided by Apple and referencing the UIKit APIs for Swift.

Here is the code I found online that creates a simple UIButton...

```
var button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, 100, 32))
button.setTitle("I'm a Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
view.addSubview(button)
```

Everything is self explanatory, but the thing I don't know understand is how we would know that UIButton has a constructor (initializer) if I don't see it listed anywhere in the [UIKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/titleForState%3a).

This is the line of code that I would like to have a better understanding on.

```
var button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, 100, 32))
```

Again, how do I know that UIButton has a constructor which gets a CGPoint as a parameter if I don't think it is listed anywhere in the [UIButton class](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/titleForState%3a)?

Thanks

Comment: FYI, thanks to Swift's type inference system, you don't need the `UIControlState`, just `.Normal` is enough.

Comment: Note that using `init(frame:)` won't allow you to specify the type of the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `UIButton` inherits initializers from its superclasses up until `NSObject`

If you check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/UIView) for `UIView`, which is the superclass of `UIControl`, which is the immediate superclass of `UIButton`, you'll see the initializer that takes the `CGRect` as parameter.

So, basically, if you want to see all initializers available to a given class, you have to look all the way up in its class hierarchy.

Comment: In Swift, it only inherits constructors from the highest class that specifies them, in this case `UIView`.

Comment: @Kevin Not sure about that. If you define an extension of `NSObject` that adds a convenience initializer, it will be available to `UIButton`.

Answer (score 2):

the referred line of code is identical to

```
UIButton * button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 20.f, 100.f, 32.f)];
```

in ObjC.

the key point is here, that `–initWithFrame:` is method of the `UIView` class, which the `UIButton` is inherited from, therefore if you need to know more about a particular method, you may need to check the parent class or its parent, etc, for find it.

in the referred documentation you find a section about *Inheritance* like:

[image: Inheritance panel]

and you can check the parent classes' methods of the actual class one-by-one. that is pretty much how you can get more information about the methods which are not 'listed' in the actual *Class Reference*.

Answer (score 0):

Part of my confusion was because I was expecting to find a constructor not an initializer.

UIView lists the itializer as follow...

```
init(frame:)
init(frame aRect: CGRect)
```

... which made sense in Objectice-C since it doesn't have constructors and uses initializers instead, but for Swift I was expecting more like a constructor, where the constructor is named the same as the class, something like...

```
UIButton (frame:)
CGRect UIButton (frame aRect: CGRect)
```

Or on this case a UIView constructor

```
UIView (frame:)
CGRect UIView (frame aRect: CGRect)
```

I don't know where I read that Swift supported constructors. I guess I need to read more about Swift and programming in general.

Thanks a